# Access a Mongo Database through MongoAS3 without compiling the password with the app

Tags: actionscript-3, mongodb

I am developing a pure AS3 AIR app(for iphone) using MongoAS3 to access a Mongo Database in my server.
MongoAS3 is cool because it doesnt need any server layer to make the communication (like PHP/ AMF). It is blazing fast.
However, this brings a security issue. The password to the DB is being compiled together with the app.
So my question is:
Is there a nice way to, using MongoAS3, to autenticate in the server using some OAUTH like approach? Without having to put my pass inside the app.

I need to read AND write in the DB.

Any thoughts will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced security is a job for a web layer, not database. I don't know any database that supports authentication via OAuth. Most of them use simple login/password authentication. Some support features like ActiveDirectory domain authentication. The rest just don't bother. It's generally recommended to not expose your database to the public internet. They (databases) are not designed for this scenario. And their auth systems might have flaws.

**TL;DR**: build a web layer and handle security there. Don't expose your database.

Comment: Definitely not a good idea to provide direct public access to a database server.  Probably worth looking into [RESTful APIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) or one of the [10gen MongoDB partners](http://www.10gen.com/partners/cloudhosting) that may provide a hosted service with APIs.